# Linq / EF in ASP.NET Blazor

Tags: entity-framework

[image: Text]

I am using Blazor.

I am trying to get a specific result from dbset.

I have two conditions, salary is 620 and deduction is for p2.

The difficult thing is range, btw 600~700 for salary. Then how I move to specific column to get the result for p2.

var result = await _db.TaxTable.......blah...blah...

In this case, I have to find the result **70**

I have tried some code..but I failed everytime.

Could you share the exact knowledge?

Thank you in adv.

Comment: `.Where(x => x.start <= salary && x.end >= salary)` ?

Comment: "I have tried some code..but I failed everytime.": please share the relevant code you tried and the describe the "failure".

Comment: I removed the Blazor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query into your DbSet should look something like this to get the specific value:

```cs
using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

var value = await dbContext.Set<TRecord>()
    .SingleOrDefault(item => item.start <= this.salary && item.end >= this.salary)?.p2 ?? 0;
```

Here's a demo page.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<input class="form-control" @bind-value=this.salary />

<div class="text-end m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Calc>Calculate</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick=Calc2>Calculate 2</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    P2 = @P2
</div>

@code {
    private int salary;
    private int P2;

    private void Calc()
    {
        var record = deductions.SingleOrDefault(item => item.start <= this.salary && item.end >= this.salary);
        P2 = record?.p2 ?? 0;
    }

    private void Calc2()
    {
        P2 = deductions.SingleOrDefault(item => item.start <= this.salary && item.end >= this.salary)?.p2 ?? 0;
    }


    private List<Deduction> deductions = new List<Deduction>
    {
      new Deduction(1,0,199,10,20,30),   
      new Deduction(2,200,299,20,30,40),
      new Deduction(3,300,399,30,40,50),
      new Deduction(4,400,499,40,50,60),
    };

    public record Deduction(int Id, int start, int end, int p1, int p2, int p3 );
}
```

Note: there's a problem in your dataset your ranges overlap!

Comment: this part looks something new for me. 'item => x => x.start...' May I ask what difference btw 'item => x => x.start' and just 'x => x.start'?

Comment: Most of all the part 'select(item => item.p2)' was what I didn't know. thank you, Mrc, I will try this.

Comment: Moreover, you will throw an exception (most of the time) if the salary is exactly equal to `x.start` or `x.end`.

Comment: I copied in the wrong text!  Here's a revised answer.

Comment: Its best they do overlap like the OP has posted and use `>=` or `<=` one side and `<` or `>` on the other respectively. This way there is no gaps. I have done these sorts of tables many times before including lab results which can have very fine resolution.

Comment: @BrianParker - I was mulling this one over this evening (UK) and I can come up with arguments for doing it either way, but in general I agree with you.  Anyway, OP's choice, he knows the context and how to do it now!

Answer (score 3):

You have to locate the row. Then use a switch statement to get the appropriate value.

```cs
double GetDeduction(double salary, string discount)
{
    var row = someData.SingleOrDefault(a => salary >= a.start && salary < a.end);

    if(row == null) throw new SomeRowNotFoundException();

    return discount switch 
    {
        "p1" => row.p1,
        "p2" => row.p2,
        "p3" => row.p3,
        _ => throw new SomeDiscountNotValidException();
    }
}
```

You have to include one of the boundaries and exclude the other to avoid overlap. I arbitrarily chose to include start the alternative would be

`someData.SingleOrDefault(a => salary > a.start && salary <= a.end)`

Comment: Yes, you exactly pointed it(overlap problem) out when I drew the image. Thank you. And it was a great tip for me to use a switch statement. I learned.